# Table doesn't exist in engine after replacing data from backup

Tags: mysql

I followed a youtube tutorial for fixing a server issue with MySQL and I pasted all the files from C:\xampp\mysql\backup to C:\xampp\mysql\data. After I reconnected I get the error table `table_name` doesn't exist in the engine. How do I fix this. thanks in advance

Comment: You can't. If the table was not in the backup, then you lost the data.

Comment: even when pasting with replace? cause the folder with my db is still there

Comment: It depends - if the data was in separate data files, then there is still hope. If not, then not. Please, ask only programming related questions on SO, all database admin related questions like this one should be asked on the DBA sister site of SO.

Comment: First you have to be sure it does exist, did it exist before the backup was taken?

Comment: yes it did and now I have a bunch of .frm and.idb files